# Why does this RegEx match this number?

Tags: javascript, regex

`/[^01235689]/.test(+n)` is matching `54` and I'm not sure why. Can this be re written in a better way?

```js
var n=54;
console.log( /[^01235689]/.test(+n) );
```

Comment: Because it matches 4. See [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Is your handle just a coincidence? :)

Comment: It would help people to provide an effective explanation if you'd explain what you think it should do and why.

Comment: "Can this be rewritten in a better way" depends on what you're trying to do? Please explain better what you're trying to do with test cases of what should pass/fail.

Comment: Try to write and test your regular expression with online tools like https://regexr.com/. You can see them parse and explain to you what you're actually writing.

Comment: That's a quite good example why you should use character classes instead of trying to make a list of your characters!

Comment: @Thefourthbird he was pointing `fourth` in your name and `4` missing in pattern in  :p

Comment: Omg how can I miss that :) I will remove the comment

Comment: Sorry about the bad formatting I posted this right before I left. I appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That regex is saying "match anything that is not one of these digits". 4 is not one of those digits, so the string matches. If you want it to say "match anything that does not include any of these digits", you want to test that every character matches that pattern from start to finish:

```
/^[^01235689]*$/.test(+n);
```

(That means "match anything that starts with any amount of characters not in this set and then ends, with nothing else in between".)

Comment: Makes total sense, sorry for the rushed post. Thanks!